# Spotlight does not show contents from internet!

Tags: macos, spotlight, internet, search

[image]

Spotlight does not show contents from the internet. It only searches my mac HD.
What should I do?

---

I am using MacBookPro Retina 13" with Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: What do you mean from the internet? The ability to perform quick search on Bing?

Comment: I mean when i search something through Spotlight app, it must show results have founded in internet in addition to results have founded inside my mac.

Comment: Wikipedia results? Can you give a screenshot or example on the web because I haven't seen any results from the "internet" in spotlight? Internet is quite vague.

Comment: I added a sample image to my question. this image is from this link: http://www.macworld.com/article/2369722/hands-on-with-os-x-yosemite-spotlight-takes-center-stage.html There is a full review of new Spotlight features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 10.13 only sixteen countries have this feature - 
http://www.apple.com/osx/feature-availability/#spotlight-suggestions

I mean your country might not be in the list yet, I'm facing the same issue

For macOS High Sierra, here is the feature list page documenting what works where.

- https://www.apple.com/macos/feature-availability/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in System Preferences > Spotlight, that you have checked the Bing Web Searches checkbox under the Search Results tab:

[image]

Comment: Bing Web Searches checkbox already has checked. 